# Reference request - Texts on geometric analysis with exercises

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, textbook-recommendation, geometric-analysis

I’ve recently been studying some Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis, however I have found it difficult to find resources with exercises to practice. It seems that many textbooks past the basics are written in monograph style.

My question is as follows - can anyone recommend resources (books, lecture notes) on geometric analysis with a good amount of exercises? I have no particular preference as to the specific topic - geometric PDE, minimal surfaces, mean curvature flow, etc are all of interest. Really I just want anything that will allow me to get a handle on geometric analysis in general.

My background is mainly in stochastic analysis, however I have gone through some Riemannian geometry at the level of, say, do Carmo’s book *Riemannian Geometry*, and the first half of Jost’s book *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*.

So far here are the books and notes I’ve found with exercises that I have read/ am currently reading through:

1. *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* by Jost
2. *Notes on Ricci Flow (285G)* by Tao
3. *Hamilton’s Ricci Flow* by Chow

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Geometric heat flows is usually considered an advanced topic, and in general there are few textbooks with exercises on advanced topics in any field. However, books like the ones you list often do not provide step-by-step proofs. So the way many of us learn advanced material like this is to work out the steps in great detail, reducing them to basic facts. At some point you will realize that you can work out many of the proofs on your own without having to read the book's or paper's proof in great detail.